# IndexedDB handle data migration onupgradeneeded

Tags: javascript, database, html, indexeddb

i'm developing a offline-webapplication with IndexedDB. So I thought a lot about data migration in case of a version change.

For example, I had 3 ObjectStores in DB Version 3. Now i noticed, that i should have a specific index at all 3 ObjectStores. But its not possible to add an index afterwards to an existing ObjectStore, without losing data.

What could be the solution to handle data migration in an "onupgradeneeded"-event?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in `onupgradeneeded`. Create/delete object stores, add/edit/delete data, add/delete indexes... all of this happens without data loss. So I don't really know what you're talking about in your question.

Comment: If you add an index to an existing ObjectStore you won't lose any data. The data that exists in the objectstore is added to the new index.

Comment: Ahhh I've overlooked that there is an transaction attribute in the requests objects :D

I've tried to start a new transaction on an objectstore... Thx for your hint! I will take a look at it.

Comment: This question probably will not help future readers.

Comment: @Josh As a future reader who felt this was useful, I am interested in hearing why it might not help. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No Need to kill the StoreObject just update it like this :**

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function(evt) {

        var dataBase = evt.target.result;
        var txn = evt.target.transaction;
        //////////
        var storeCreateIndex = function (objectStore, name, options) {
            if (!objectStore.indexNames.contains(name)) {
                objectStore.createIndex(name, name, options);
            }
        }
        //////////
        var catalogItem, mangaItem, chapterItem, artworkItem;
        if (evt.newVersion != evt.oldVersion) {
            // Get exiting objectStore
            catalogItem = txn.objectStore('CatalogItem');
            mangaItem = txn.objectStore('MangaItem');
            chapterItem = txn.objectStore('ChapterItem');
            artworkItem = txn.objectStore('ArtworkList');
        } else {
            // Fist creation of database objectStore
            catalogItem = dataBase.db.createObjectStore("CatalogItem", { keyPath: "key" });
            mangaItem = dataBase.db.createObjectStore("MangaItem", { keyPath: "key" });
            chapterItem = dataBase.db.createObjectStore("ChapterItem", { keyPath: "key" });
            artworkItem = dataBase.db.createObjectStore("ArtworkList", { keyPath: "key" });
        }
        //////////
        storeCreateIndex(catalogItem, "popularity", { unique: false });
        storeCreateIndex(catalogItem, "author", { unique: false });
        storeCreateIndex(catalogItem, "status", { unique: false });
        storeCreateIndex(catalogItem, "isFavorite", { unique: false });
        storeCreateIndex(chapterItem, "isBookmarked", { unique: false });
        storeCreateIndex(chapterItem, "isDownloaded", { unique: false });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments above:

Attempting to initiate a new transaction from "onupgradeneeded" will result the error:

> InvalidStateError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 11

Instead use the transaction referenced by the request object. Example:

```
function opendb(oncomplete){
  var version = 1;
  var migrateobjects = [];
  var request = indexedDB.open('mydb', version);

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    db = e.target.result;
    transaction = e.target.transaction;

    if(db.objectStoreNames.contains('myobjects')){ 
      migraterequest = transaction.objectStore('myobjects').openCursor();
      migraterequest.onsuccess = function(e){ 
        var cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor){
          migrateobjects.push(cursor.value);
          cursor.continue();
        }
      };
      db.deleteObjectStore('myobjects');
    }

    var store = db.createObjectStore('myobjects', {keyPath: 'id'});
  };

  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    db = e.target.result;
    transaction = db.transaction('myobjects', 'readwrite')
    store = transaction.objectStore('myobjects');
    for(var i=0; i < migrateobjects.length; ++i)
      store.put(migrateobjects[i]);
    transaction.oncomplete = oncomplete;
  };
};
```

Comment: The migraterequest.onsuccess handler can (and will likely) get called after the db.deleteObjectStore('myobjects') call below it, so you'd need to put in some means of making the store deletion (and subsequent createObjectStore) only occur after the migrationrequest has completed. Similar restriction applies to the request.onsuccess handler code (this should only execute after migrationrequest.onsuccess, and the subsequent delete/create object store commands are completed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing index should not clear existing records unless new index violate database constraint of existing records. But I do observe object store blow away in Chrome but not in Firefox.